# Binding a source to a control in Visual Studio (Windows Form)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

In old versions of Visual Studio for binging a source to a control of windows form it was so easy, as you can see in the [Example of use](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/main/docs/data-tools/bind-windows-forms-controls-to-data-in-visual-studio.md)

The problem is that in Visual Studio 2022 (Versión 17.5.4) when you try to drag and drop the controls to the windows form, nothing happens. I mean, it doesn't work.

Does any one face this problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry ridiculous answer. Use copy / paste in stead of drag / drop!
Amazing!!! ;)